# Orthogonal complement of orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be some linear space. $S^{\perp}=\{y\;|\;\forall x\in S: \langle x,y \rangle=0\}$. So, how do I prove that $(S^{\perp})^{\perp}=S$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S$ must be a subspace of some vector space $V$. Say dimension of $V$ be $n$. Then dimension of $S^{\perp}$ is $n-\dim S$. Then the dimension of $(S^{\perp})^{\perp}$ is same as the dimension of $S$. Moreover it is obvious that $S\subseteq (S^{\perp})^{\perp}$. Hence we are done.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\text{Let } \vec{x} \in (S^\perp)^\perp\subseteq S\\
\Rightarrow x = \vec{u} + \vec{v} \text{ for some } \vec{u} \in S, \vec{v} \in S^\perp\\
\langle\vec{x},\vec{v}\rangle = 0\\
\Rightarrow \langle\vec{u}+\vec{v}, \vec{v}\rangle = 0\\
\Rightarrow \langle\vec{u}, \vec{v}\rangle+\langle\vec{v},\vec{v}\rangle = 0\\
\Rightarrow 0 + ||\vec{v}|| = 0\\
\Rightarrow \vec{v} = 0\\
\Rightarrow\vec{x} = \vec{u}\\
\Rightarrow \forall \vec{x} \in (S^\perp)^\perp.\vec{x} \in S\\
\Rightarrow (S^\perp)^\perp \subseteq S
$$
$\supseteq$ is the same.